# Absolute continuity of a value function (envelope theorem)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, optimization, continuity

Reading [this article](http://web.stanford.edu/~milgrom/publishedarticles/Envelope%20Theorems.pdf) but can't figure out the following implication at the end of Theorem 2. Suppose $f(x,t)$ is absolutely continuous for all $t \in [0,1]$ and that there exists an integrable function $b:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $|f_{t}(x,t)| \leq b(t)$ for all $x \in X$. It can then be shown that for all $t',t'' \in [0,1]$ with $t' < t''$:

\begin{equation}
|\sup_{x \in X}f(x,t'') - \sup_{x \in X}f(x,t')| \leq \int_{t'}^{t''}\sup_{x \in X}|f_{t}(x,s)|ds \leq \int_{t'}^{t''}b(s)ds,
\end{equation}

and this supposedly implies that $V(t) := \sup_{x \in X}f(x,t)$ is absolutely continuous. Can anyone give a pointer or a reference as to why this is the case?

EDIT 1:

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and there exists an integrable function $b:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that for all $t'',t' \in [0,1]$ with t' < t'':

\begin{equation}
0 \leq |f(t'') - f(t')| \leq \int_{t'}^{t''}b(s)ds,
\end{equation}

then $f$ is continuous (by the squeeze theorem and dominated convergence), so by Theorem 1 of https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_continuity, $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I have however not been able to find another reference than the above link (also note that the only difference between the above statement and Theorem 1 in the link is that the the dominating function $b$ above is nonnegative).

EDIT 2:

The above result is apparently "well known" according to this post.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188093/absolutely-continuous-functions

EDIT 3:

We know that there exists an integrable function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

\begin{equation*}
0 \leq |f(t'') - f(t')| \leq \int_{t'}^{t''}g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{t''}g(s)ds - \int_{0}^{t'}g(s)ds,
\end{equation*}

for all $t',t'' \in [0,1]$ with $t' < t$. Now the function $h$ defined by:

\begin{equation*}
h(t) = \int_{0}^{t}g(s)ds,
\end{equation*}

is absolutely continuous (see equation (3) in the [wikipedia article on absolute continuity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), i.e. for $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all finite collections $[a_{k},b_{k}]$ of disjoint sub-intervals of [0,1] such that:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k}(b_{k} - a_{k}) < \delta \implies \sum_{k}|h(b_{k}) - h(a_{k})| < \varepsilon,
\end{equation*}

but by the above inequality this implies that for $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k}(b_{k} - a_{k}) < \delta \implies \sum_{k}|f(b_{k}) - f(a_{k})| \leq \sum_{k}|h(b_{k}) - h(a_{k})| < \varepsilon,
\end{equation*}

and thus $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: The theorem you need is a consequence of the fact that $\int_{t_0}^{t}b(s)ds$ is absolutely continuous for integrable $b$, see for example Lemma 3.31 in Leoni's "A First Course in Sobolev Spaces"

Comment: Thanks a ton! Think I managed to sort it out (see edit 3).

Comment: Looks good. To be a bit picky, I would say "for $\epsilon>0$" instead of "for all" since that way it implies the $\delta$ is the same for all $\epsilon$ which it doesn't have to be I think. Also, on the last calculations you write $g$ instead of $h$ which is what you probably mean.

Comment: Edited and yes, I meant $h$. Again, thanks a lot for the help!